# How can you format rows of text to offset in PowerPoint

Tags: text, alignment, microsoft-powerpoint

I am trying to skew rows of text in a PowerPoint textbox automatically.

Example:
[image: Screenshot of a PowerPoint textbox with lines of indented text]

I have been able to achieve these results through manual means, such as adding leading spaces or adding a textbox for each line of text. But I have not found a method/format to achieve this type of slanted text automatically.

Additionally, if this is not achievable natively in PowerPoint, is there a different option to achieve these results? (ideal one native to Windows or MS Office)